# Text select (ready to use clipboard operations)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap/

in this website when i mouseover the links given the text is selected(like the mouse text select and not css styling).

i tried to check what's changing in inspect element i found none.

i tried to find out if js or jquery has methods to do this.
i found .select() method of jquery but its usable only on form elements and there is no deselect() method in jquery so its definetely no that.

so whats under the hood?

UPDATE:

i found this [solution](http://coderzone.org/library/Select-text-in-a-DIV-SPAN-or-table-cell_1047.htm) 
i tried it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avi_sagi/pGpUR/) it works perfect.
but its written in js with dom node manupulations and it just looks like greek and latin to me. i am not able to write the jquery version of this algorithm.

HTML:

```
<p id="selectable">hello</p>
```

JS:

```
function fnSelect(objId) {
    fnDeSelect();
    if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(objId));
    range.select();
    }
    else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById(objId));
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
}

function fnDeSelect() {
    if (document.selection) document.selection.empty(); 
    else if (window.getSelection)
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").on("mouseover",function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        fnSelect(id);
    });    
    $("p").on("mouseout",function(){
        fnDeSelect();
   });
});
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+select+text&oq=javascript+select+text&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Why did someone downvote this it's actually a legit question and the `select()` method is used for input fields not static DOM elements like `<p>` or `<tr>` (which is used on the CDNJS site)

Comment: dang didn't see your update til I posted mine.  Bummer.  Glad I found that though.  I'm sure it'll come in handy on a rainy afternoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding this was way more trouble than it should have been.  Here's exactly what you can use:

**[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection.selectAllChildren)**

```
window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(elementObject);
```

**[Extended studies found here (MDN again)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)**

If it were me, I would do this to achieve the effect:

```
function onMouseOver(e) {
    window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(e.currentTarget);
}
function onMouseOut(e) {
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(e.currentTarget);
}
document.getElementById("top").addEventListener("mouseenter", onMouseOver, false);
document.getElementById("top").addEventListener("mouseleave", onMouseOut, false);
```

## [Live Demo :)](http://jsfiddle.net/SQyy3/)

Comment: i wanted the jquery version anyways after finding that update
u just gave me the simplest jquery code thanks man

Comment: no problemo.  I was actually gonna simplify it with jQ but got distracted haha thanks for pushin me past 4000 tho ;)